# How to hide some categories in dashboard

Tags: categories, filters, dashboard

Is there a way to hide some categories in the dashboard for some users/roles so they won't appear? It should affect both the dropdown menu in the post list and the category checkbox selector in the post page:

[image: screenshot #1]
and

[image: screenshot #2]

Comment: It would be rather messy. You could add a custom capability and filter the list but what if your user adds a category that clashes with a hidden one? Maybe a custom taxonomy with this restriction would suit your needs better.

Comment: The role for these users prevents them to adding categories. Tell me more how would you do this. BTW I am already filtering visible posts by category in the dashboard, however the category list is complete and would like to hide unwanted items

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far for yourself. You might find it helpful to review [ask]

Comment: Well at the moment I have filtered posts in functions.php so for some roles they won't be visible. Category based. I have made no attempt to hide selected categories in dashboard but I am aware of testing user roles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook to the `get_terms_args` filter conditionally depending on your user/role

Something along those lines

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'restrict_cat', 10, 2 );
function restrict_cat( $args, $taxonomies ){

  // Don't run if we are not dealing with categories
  if( 'category' != $taxonomies[0] )
    return $args;

  // The check for the user we want to restrict
  // you could use current_user_can( $capability ) or test for a specific role here
  if( 1 == get_current_user_id() ){
    $args['exclude'] = array( 
        'cat_id1',
        'cat_id2' 
    );

    return $args;
  }

  return $args;
}
```

check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/ for a list of available args.

Comment: Edited the code, after some testing, I found that my first answer was throwing some errors and disabling all categories for that specific user. This should now work

Comment: I'm glad I could help! cheers :)